# Conditions for Arc Length Formula

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ have a continuous first derivative on the interval $[a,b]$. Then the length of the curve from $(a,f(a))$ to $(b,f(b))$ is

$$L=\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\, dx.$$

$f$ has to be differentiable to use the Mean Value Theorem and $f'$ has to be continuous for $\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}$ to be integrable.

But when we say $f$ is continuosly differentiable on $[a,b]$, at the end points $a,b$, do we mean one-sided continuity and differentiability?

Comment: Yes. The two sides simply don't exist at $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Moreover it is sufficient that $f'$ is integrable.

Comment: Note that the arc length in question exists if and if only if the function $f$ is of bounded variation. The need for derivative arises only for the existence of the formula of arc-length in terms of integral.

Comment: Both one-sided limits,  $\lim\limits_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ and $\lim\limits_{h\to0^-}\dfrac{f(b+h)-f(b)}{h}$ have to exist so that the formula makes sense. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right. Those limits are $f'(a), f'(b) $. But note that these are not necessary conditions for existence of arc-length.